# Cassandra not connecting from other machine

Tags: cassandra, database-connection

I was googling about the cassandra.yaml file's setting in Windows and followed the steps you shared. After making those changes in the config file I started my cassandra service. Then I tried to connect it through my one of the nodeJS server by following line of code to create keyspace:

```
var cassandraDriver = require('cassandra-driver');
var client = new cassandraDriver.Client({
    contactPoints: ['MyCassandra system IP:9042']
});

client.connect(function(e) {
    var query;
    query = "CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS pawandemo WITH replication =
        {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '3' }";
    return client.execute(query, function(e, res) {
        return console.log(e, res);
    });
});
```

But I am getting the following error:-

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gMWJ.jpg

Any Help will be appreciated.

Thanks Pawan

Comment: Can you also post the cassandra.yaml? Only the parts with an IP. Seeds etc.

Comment: Is your cassandra running on local? It seems a running C* can't be found on the IP you mentioned. If it's on your local, try `127.0.0.1`